# how do i get values from a properties file in quartz scheduler?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm using spring 2.0.6 and quartz 1.5.2 in a java based webapp.  Want to know how to configure my applicationContext-quartz.xml such that i can read values from a properties file. i.e. I would like to have my file read

```
<property name="imageFolder" value="${config.imageFolder}" />
<property name="rawImageFolder" value="${config.rawImageFolder}" />
<property name="imageOutputFolder" value="${config.imageOutputFolder}" />
```

instead of

```
<property name="imageFolder" value="/path/to/dir1" />
<property name="rawImageFolder" value="/path/to/dir2" />
<property name="imageOutputFolder" value="/path/to/dir3" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` mechanism](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <!-- change this to your property location -->
        <value>classpath:quartz.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I was trying to use a new property file to specify configurations but I already had one. When i specified my existing properties file and added attributes it started to work fine. Thanks for the help!